# How to implement a zip function for the SwiftTask framework?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement a generic `Task.zip` class function for the [SwiftTask](https://github.com/ReactKit/SwiftTask) framework. The function takes a tuple of tasks and returns a task of tuples much like the standard library function [zip](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs3zipu0_Rq_Ss12SequenceTypeq0_S__FTq_q0__GVSs12Zip2Sequenceq_q0__) and is a type of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)).

My first attempt used the following signature:

`class func zip<P1, V1, R1, P2, V2, R2>(task1: Task<P1, V1, R1>, _ task2: Task<P2, V2, R2>) -> Task<(P1, P2), (V1, V2), (R1?, R2?)>`

Although the function compiles, calling it triggers the follow types of compiler error:

`'Cannot invoke 'zip' with an argument list of type '(Task<String, String, NSError>, Task<NSRange, Float, NSError>)'`

Following is a sketch of the implementation (untested). Getting the call site to compile is a first step.

```
public class func zip<P1, V1, R1, P2, V2, R2>(task1: Task<P1, V1, R1>, _ task2: Task<P2, V2, R2>) -> Task<(P1, P2), (V1, V2), (R1?, R2?)>
{
    return Task<(P1, P2), (V1, V2), (R1?, R2?)> { progress, fulfill, reject, configure in

        var completedCount = 0
        var rejectedCount = 0
        let totalCount = 2

        let cancelAll : Void -> Void = {
            task1.cancel()
            task2.cancel() 
        }

        let pauseAll : Void -> Void = {
            task1.pause()
            task2.pause() 
        }

        let resumeAll : Void -> Void = {
            task1.resume()
            task2.resume() 
        }

        task1.success { (value: V1) -> Void in

            synchronized(self) 
            {
               completedCount++

                if completedCount == totalCount 
                {
                    fulfill( (task1.value!, task2.value!) )
                }
            }
        }.failure { (error, isCancelled) -> Void in

            synchronized(self) 
            {
                reject( error, nil )
                cancelAll() 
            }
        }

        task2.success { (value: V2) -> Void in

            synchronized(self) 
            {
                completedCount++

                if completedCount == totalCount 
                {
                    fulfill( (task1.value!, task2.value!) )
                }
            }
        }.failure { (error, isCancelled) -> Void in

            synchronized(self) 
            {
                reject( nil, error )
                cancelAll() 
            }
        }

    configure.pause = { pauseAll() }
    configure.resume = { resumeAll() }
    configure.cancel = { cancelAll() }

    }.name("Task.zip")
}
```

And call site:

```
let task1 = listener as Task<String, String, NSError> 
let task2 = praise as Task<NSRange, Float, NSError> 
let zipped = Task.zip(task1, task2)

// Error: Cannot invoke 'zip' with an argument list of type '(Task<String, String, NSError>, Task<NSRange, Float, NSError>)'
```

I understand that a `Task.zip` maybe wrong-headed, or that the implementation is incorrect. Please let me know your thoughts - all help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - got an answer to my tricky generics issue. The problem seems to be that I defined `Task.zip` as a generic class function on a generic type (i.e. on the class `Task<Progress, Value, Error>`). For some reason unknown to me (perhaps a compiler bug/feature?) this causes the call site error listed above. There are at least two workarounds:

1) Define the class function on a non-generic type (e.g. `TaskExtension.zip`)

2) Define as a member function, a possible signature being:

`func zip<Progress2, Value2, Error2>(task2: Task<Progress2, Value2, Error2>) -> Task<(Progress, Progress2), (Value, Value2), (Error?, Error2?)>`

Happy `SwiftTask`'ing!